# When is the term "droppings" used?

Tags: word-usage

When is the term "droppings" used for faecal matter, and when is it not applicable?

I can see the term being used for rats, insects, or birds, but can't envisage it being used for humans or cows or elephants. Does size and/or moisture content play a role?

The Free Dictionary, citing Collins English Dictionary, [says](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/droppings)

> the dung of certain animals, such as rabbits, sheep, and birds

which suggests there's a logic as to when the term is used, but isn't too specific.

Comment: I won't close vote here, though you could have provided some research findings. There are, for instance, over 30 000 Google hits in a search for "elephant droppings". I'd say that 'droppings' is rarely appropriate for human faeces, as it implies 'faeces dropped on the ground'. But the size factor **is** probably involved, with the term being more usually used for less sizeable leavings.

Comment: The size of a drop (water, tear, etc.) is quite small.

Comment: It's generally used to refer to the fecal matter of smaller animals, but is sometimes used (with perhaps a hint of sarcasm) for the output of larger animals.  I suspect that if you examine uses of "elephant droppings" you will find many instances are being somewhat sarcastic.

Comment: *Droppings* is basically a top level hypernym. It isn't ever really wrong, but often, there are more idiomatic terms depending on the situation. http://aem.asm.org/content/71/11/7285.full

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, *droppings* would be appropriate only for fecal material of non-human hosts. I've seen it usually paired with birds, insects, and rodents ([that's how the Oxford Dictionary defines it too](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/droppings)). I feel like droppings is appropriate when the origin of fecal materials is from individual (or few hosts). In the context of large quantity of fecal material, other terms such as *scat*, *excrement*, *feces*, or *waste* may be appropriate. There may be other words to describe large quantity of non-human fecal material depending on animal type too (e.g., *dung* for cattle).

Answer (score 4):

The term is used to refer to the faeces of animals, irrespective of their size:

***[Droppings](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/droppings)***

> - The excrement of animals.

(AHD)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cow%20droppings%2Celephant%20droppings&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccow%20droppings%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Celephant%20droppings%3B%2Cc0): *cow, elephant droppings.*

It is less commonly used referring to human beings:

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=human%20droppings%2C%20animal%20droppings&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chuman%20droppings%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canimal%20droppings%3B%2Cc0): *human vs animal droppings*.

[image]